# C++ <ctime> printing wrong date

Tags: c++, datetime, epoch

I am working on a small project using a small pcb micro computer. I have wrote out some code to get the date and time and print this but it is printing the wrong date. The date it is printing started at:

Jan 1 00:00:00 2066

The code segment i am using is below with non relevant bits stripped out. Any help to fix this issue would be helpful

```
 #include<ctime>



static char* DateTime()
{
   time_t now = time(0);  
   char* dateTime = ctime(&now);
    return dateTime;
};
```

I have read some other similar questions but i have not been able to successfully derive a solution, i feel the fact i am using a micro computer might be playing a role in my problem. The board i am using is STM32 Nucleo.

Comment: The necessary header is `<time.h>` in C. C11 draft standard n1570: *7.27.2.4 The time function
1 #include <time.h>
time_t time(time_t *timer);
3 [...] The value (time_t)(-1) is returned if the calendar time is not available. [...]*

Comment: The `#include` line is not valid in C. You you use C++, change text and tag. They are different languages. C also does not support _methods_. See [ask], it is not even clear what your actual problem is. However, on MCUs typically only a freestanding environment exists, so all or part of the standard library may be not available.

Comment: my bad, i knew what i meant minor slip up, corrected it to properly point to the right language.

Comment: also <time.h> does the same thing as <ctime> in regards to the date format. been 2066 jan

Comment: Your _function_ still is not a _method_. In C++ the differentiation becomes even more relevant, as both are possible. The rest of my comment is still valid. Are you sure the function exists and yields any valid result? Did you check for _null pointer_? Your question is incomplete.

Comment: it compiles and prints out a date/time. The date time updates every second so i know its not static. if this method is wrong and there is another could you point me towards it.

Comment: @MattFarrell Well, how was time set on your board?

Comment: that i have no idea, currently its plugged into the computer i hoped it would pull the current datetime from that, but im quite likely mistaken and naive.

Comment: Just because it compiles and prints something doesn't mean it's actually working.  You need to show how you're entering, exiting, storing and printing.  The question is incomplete.

Comment: Currently the program takes the time using ctime, it does this every 2 seconds and stores the time in a character array, it also prints this character array every 2 seconds as well.

But for some reason it is printing the date as 2066. Even though I am using &now. I am unsure why it is doing this, but as far as I am concerned it is printing the time as it has been updating whilst it has been running and is not a static value.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the embedded boards have a clock that resets every time you reset the cpu. Unless you have explicitly set the date, there is no way the board can learn the actual time.

Computers use the NTP protocol to update the time automatically, this is not true for microcontroller without some kind to OS(ex. Raspberry).

In projects like clocks it is typical to use an external clock IC which keeps the date and time, and use a small battery to be able to have power 24/7 and not lose the date.

Here is a page that provides more info on the topic and how to deal with time on microcontroller https://learn.adafruit.com/ds1307-real-time-clock-breakout-board-kit

Comment: Thank you, this is quite useful. do you know how i could get it to call the time from the computer as its always going to be plugged into a computer when operating. Meaning its time is not relevant only the time of its source ie the computer is.